# Can't access Wordpress site after IP change

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running a **multi-site** wordpress install on a virtual machine in the cloud. The WP didn't have a domain, I was accessing it purely through IP address. Today, I turned the VM off/on and lo and behold, I got a new IP address. Now, I can't access it.

Whenever, I go to the new IP address, Chrome will spin for a few seconds and then load up the old IP address as the URL and display a message saying the site took too long to respond.

I've already done the following:

1. Updated IP address in `wp-config.php` file.
2. Updated IP address in siteurl and home in `wp_3_options`, `wp_2_options`, etc.
3. Updated IP Address in `wp_blogs`, `wp_site`, `wp_sitemeta`, `wp_options`.
4. Renamed plugins folder so they wouldn't reload. I have Wordfence installed and there's a column called `wp_home_url` that contains the old IP, but it's a BLOB.

Not sure what else to check. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this?

Running WP 4.7 on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Clear browser cache. Check mysql and webserver are running after restart.

Comment: @Juan Thanks, it was the browser cache! It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan was right, I just needed to clear the browser cache. I followed this article to update the URL on a multisite WP installation; https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain. The article didn't mention that the browser cache had to be cleared and that's where I got stuck.

Comment: I too have now faced a similar issue but this worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link! Mine is not related to the cache but rather a database value that was not updated. The instructions in the link provided extra places to check.